# How to access a hprof file dumped on the remote JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, heap-dump

I'm using `HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean` to capture a heapdump of a java process running on the remote machine. `HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean` only exposes `dumpHeap` api which writes a file and persists on the remote machine itself with restrictive access (No read and write except JVM process owner). It may be due to security issues.
So in this situation -

1. How to read heapdump file?
2. Is there any alternative to `HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean`?

NOTE: I'm using Oracle jdk 1.8_62

`dumpHeap` api - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html#dumpHeap-java.lang.String-boolean-

Comment: The JVM always dumps heap into a file. Specify an accessible file path or ask your system administrator to give you the heap dump from the server.

Comment: The intention is to automate the heapdump process w/o involving sysadmin.

Comment: So what is the problem? If you were to get any other file from a remote system, how would you do that?